# how to know Content-Length of my Request Body in order to add it in my request header

Tags: go, http-headers, httprequest, content-length

I have this code:

```
type myStruct struct {
    ID               string `json:"id"`
    Nombre           string `json:"nombre"`
    Date             time.Time `json:"date"`
}

func sendJson(data myStruct,url string) error {
    jsonString, _:= json.Marshal(data)
    pedir, _ := http.NewRequest("PATCH",url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonString))
    pedir.Header.Add("Content-Length", ?????)
    .....    
}
```

But, I don´t know how to get the length; I´ve been searching on internet with no solution found, and in case you wonder why do I need to add Content-Length if mostly it is not required, I´m using some apis from google that says explicity I need to add this header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of [`http.NewRequest(method, url string, body io.Reader) (*Request, error)`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest) states:

> ...
>   If body is of type *bytes.Buffer, *bytes.Reader, or *strings.Reader, the returned request's ContentLength is set to its exact value (instead of -1), GetBody is populated (so 307 and 308 redirects can replay the body), and Body is set to NoBody if the ContentLength is 0.

You're passing `*bytes.Buffer` to `NewRequest`, then you can set the content length by:

```
pedir.Header.Add("Content-Length", strconv.FormatInt(pedir.ContentLength, 10))
```

**Note**:
As pointed by @MichaelHampton, you don't need to set the `Content-Length` explicitly. It will be added (by the lib) when needed. The documentation of [`http.Request.Header`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) also states it clearly.

Comment: It doesn't matter, because if ContentLength is > 0, then the request will send the header itself. It's not necessary to generate it yourself, and Request will ignore it anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you, I've added it to the answer.